# Get multiple elements from span inside of div - Python 3 Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract two elements from span inside of div.

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="market_commodity_buyrequests">
    <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">16337</span> 
    " requests to buy at "
    <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">$6.67</span> 
    " or lower"
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the second element (the price) from span but can only seem to get the first element to show up. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29')
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="market_commodity_buyrequests"]//span[@class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote"]')
print(data.text)
```

which returns the response:

```
16337
```

I need it to return the "$6.67" instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using find_element which is singular and only gets one element.
Use find_elements to get all of them and then loop through them to find your specific need.